# Visual Studio Application going into Break Mode after hitting API

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am using Visual Studio 2019, I have created an API project on Dot Net Core Entity Framework. There is one API when I hit, My application goes into Break Mode. I am not able to find the issue. Please help..

Exception : "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
"

Comment: Very hard to say without code. My best shot in the dark is that you have registered a Type with dependency injection that takes itself as a constructor parameter.

Comment: @Crowcoder, I think there is a Circular Dependency Issue. But I am not able to find it.. Is there any tool to find circular dependency?

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that specifically finds circular dependencies. If you have VS Enterprise then [code maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/map-dependencies-across-your-solutions?view=vs-2017) might help.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution file, click properties go to the Startup project node (if it is not already selected) Next select Multiple startup projects. Select your website and your webservice and in the Action column make sure both of them have "Start" selected.
Now when you debug your website and put a break point in your webservice, it should hit the break point.